# ASP.NET Login control not working in Release mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a simple Login control in my ASP.NET 4.0 application -- Here's the provider section in my web.config:

```
<providers>
    <clear />
        <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" />
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
</providers>
```

When I run in Debug mode from VS 2010, everything works fine. When I run in Release mode, only the Page_PreInit event is fired, nothing else happens, and then my browser says it could not connect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post error please. By in "Release mode" do you mean you publish it somewhere? Sounds like your connection string ApplicationServices is not correct when in Release mode.

Comment: Is the database with the asp.net membership table available for the release mode?